# phusion passenger (3.0.17) + nginx with parallels plesk 11

Tags: nginx, passenger, plesk, phusion, dedicated-hosting

I am planning to buy an Linux dedicated server for ruby on rails hosting, it uses plesk 11 for server administration.

As I read the release notes of plesk 11 http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP11/11.0/release-notes/parallels-plesk-panel-11.0-for-linux-based-os.html, it uses nginx (1.3) for plesk server administration.

What my question is, I am using ruby on rails application going to run on phusion passenger with nginx module , **whether  passenger nginx and plesk nginx will conflict or setting up plesk 11 with phussion passenger nginx  module is feasible or not**.

Have anyone experienced with above scenario, please share your thoughts, opinions, **workarounds** and reviews.

Answer (score 1):

Though I've never tried it personally, but my understanding is that Phusion Passenger and Plesk Nginx are likely to conflict. Nginx in Plesk is set up as a reverse proxy and Phusion Passenger would need Nginx as an actual web server. It has been announced a couple of times, that Plesk will support Nginx as actual web server, but it is not available yet.

I can see two options here

1. Either to try Phusion Passenger for Apache and install it together with Apache in Plesk
2. Or try Phusion Passenger for Nginx w/o Plesk Nginx. This way you actually are going to have 2 independent web servers on one machine - your own Nginx and Plesk Apache. You will need to put them on different ports and Plesk would know nothing about your Nginx. I don't see much sense in this configuration - Plesk will be completely useless here.